# SDL build system - When I link against `gnustl_shared` I get "Error: Cannot load library: ..." at runtime

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, sdl, sdl-2

I'm trying to compile a C++ application for android. I use project for android NDK that comes with SDL library.

When I use `APP_STL := gnustl_static` it compiles and runs fine, but I need `gnustl_shared` because my project uses multiple `.so` files. `APP_STL := gnustl_shared` gives me following runtime error at emulator:

[image]

I followed an advice from similar SO post and added

```
static {System.loadLibrary("gnustl_shared");}
```

to the end of `SDLActivity.java : class SDLMain`, but it had no visible effect.

If it matters, `libgnustl_shared.so` in all `libs/*/` directories.

**What do I need to do to fix gnustl_shared?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YEAH, solved.

```
protected String[] getLibraries() {
    return new String[] {
        "gnustl_shared", // I've added this line
        "SDL2",
        "main"
    };
}
```